# Theravada - Death and rebirth

Tags: theravada, karma, rebirth

Recently I did my research and getting familiar with actual teachings of Buddha.
Here are my questions.

2 : There are some kids who can/ could remember things from their past life. Could this be true? If it is true how come?

And correct me if I'm wrong. According to my understanding, Everything including humans belongs to the nature. Human body is made of energies, atoms, molecules etc. When the body dies, those energies don't die with it. They take another form. Like the mango tree example.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Charith and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have also a [*Help Center*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) with useful resources for new users that you might like.

Comment: There have been more than a hundred questions about "rebirth" already on this site, including [If there is no soul, how can there be rebirth?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26/254) and [many others](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebirth). Maybe we shouldn't have another new "what is reborn?" question. Instead I recommend you read some of the existing topics (questions and answers) which are tagged [tag:rebirth] and if you still have questions then ask a more specific question (for example, ask a question about one of the answers).

Comment: I'm closing this question as per duplicate.